# Why is the output of this echo command over-running into multiple lines?

Tags: linux, find, newlines, echo

I have a directory of photos whose names are the time and date the photo was taken. E.g:

```
~$ ls directory -1
2003-09-15 03.30.33.jpg
2004-05-04 12.45.28.jpg
2004-05-04 12.45.51.jpg
```

However, if I run this command as part of a `for` loop, and echo the output, the spaces in the filenames are treated as new lines:

```
~$ for pic in `ls directory -1` ; do echo  "$pic"; done
2003-09-15
03.30.33.jpg
2004-05-04
12.45.28.jpg
2004-05-04
12.45.51.jpg
```

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers intimate, the problem is how the loop is processing the output of the `ls` command.  When a string is used in the `for` loop as you have it, the string gets split into different words (based on the value of `IFS` as Darren says), and subject to globbing and the like.  That means that you are passing a string that gets split both by the line and the spaces within the line, then each of those words in turn gets set in `pic`.

Kamil's suggestion solves this problem because you let the glob expand to all the file names directly, and the entire filename is then assigned to `pic`.

That word splitting will happen anywhere that you use the `pic` variable later though, so if you do not want that to happen be sure to put double quotes around it.  E.g.,

```
for pic in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "$pic"
done
```

to print each of the names, one per line.

Answer (score 3):

In your case plain shell globbing may be enough:

```
for pic in * ; do …
```

This way you also avoid parsing `ls` which is in general [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Yes, this is working better thanks! I was ultimately trying to plumb the output into a find command to search for duplicates and that wasn't working either until I used your method.

Answer (score 1):

Question answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22319/spaces-as-line-breaks-from-inline-for-loop-command?rq=1). The short answer is to run this command:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\t\n\0")
```